# How do I get partition id from java stored procedure in voltdb

Tags: voltdb

I am having a single partitioned java stored procedure in Voltdb. I need to get the partition id of the current partition in which the procedure is running. How do I get that within the procedure?

Comment: There isn't a public API for this.  Can you explain why you want to do this within a procedure?

Comment: I wanted to know how many transaction went through a partition by adding count into a table with primary key as partiton_id

Answer (score 0):

Rather than maintaining your own transaction counts in a table, you could call the @Statistics system procedure:

SQL> exec @Statistics PROCEDUREPROFILE 0;

This provides statistics for each procedure for each partition.

SQL> exec @Statistics TABLE 0;

This provides the count of how many records per table per partition.